# perf_event_open syscall maximum events supported?

Tags: linux, performance, perf

From manpage of `perf_event_open`, the 2nd argument is the specified PID which needed to be profiled.

After managing to open all PMU events with specified PID(process mode), I tried to open PMU events with PID=-1 (system mode) at the same time. Good thing is that syscall returned normal number which indicates file descriptor(fd) while in sysmode `read` returned normal and read normal counts but process mode read 0 count.

By the way, `perf stat -e` showed the same result.

['perf stat -e' with specified program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcIwi.png)

['perf stat -e' with no specified program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OVDq.png)

Is there a limit for perf_event_open while open events under sysmode and process mode ?

Comment: The kernel will multiplex them for you if you use more than the hardware can count simultaneously (for hardware events that need to be counted by programming HW counters).  So I don't think there's a limit to how many events you can pass to the syscall.  But for any given CPU, there's a limit to how many HW PMU events it can count at any one time.  (e.g. 8 per physical core on Skylake, with hyperthreading enabled meaning you can only ever count 4 on a logical core even if the sibling core is idle.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any suggestions how to find those limits for arm64?

Comment: If you get multiplexing (numbers in parens in the right-hand column like you're getting), use fewer events.  If not, use more events, until you find the exact number.  Likely something like 4 or 8, so start your binary search around there.